# How do I resolve the following "NoClassDefFoundError" in my Apache Tika code?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I have a simple class that Utilizes Apache Tika 1.14, and it is shown here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.mime.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.apache.tika.config.*;


public class TikaExtraction {

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {

      //Assume sample.txt is in your current directory              
      File file = new File("sample.txt");

      //Instantiating Tika facade class
      Tika tika = new Tika();
      String filecontent = tika.parseToString(file);
      System.out.println("Extracted Content: " + filecontent);
   }

}
```

However, when  I try to run it, I am getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/tika/mime/MimeTypesReader
>           at org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypesFactory.create(MimeTypesFactory.java:158)
>           at org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes(MimeTypes.java:577)
>           at org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig.getDefaultMimeTypes(TikaConfig.java:73)
>           at org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig.(TikaConfig.java:222)
>           at org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig(TikaConfig.java:345)
>           at org.apache.tika.Tika.(Tika.java:116)
>           at TikaExtraction.main(TikaExtraction.java:17) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypesReader
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 7 more

When I search through the Tika library code, I am not seeing the `.class` file for the `MimeTypesReader` class.  Is there a way to comment out some code or fix this  - how would I resolve this error message?

Or could this be an issue with the version of Tika that I'm using (i.e the referenced code was from 1.6, and maybe I have 1.13 or 1.14).

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941870/tika-1-13-runtimeexception

Comment: I suppose your Tika library may be corrupted or missing files. I checked the jar file and found the  MimeTypesReader ,try this jar. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core/1.14

Comment: Using Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies will mostly prevent this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

With such type of library errors, it is not removing something, but adding something that is missing, hence the `ClassNotFoundError`. Most of the time, you are either missing some supporting jar or there are compatibility issues due to library updates. In fact, you said it yourself

> When I search through the Tika library code, I am not seeing the `.class` file for the `MimeTypesReader` class.

This is the library method that throws the exception:

```
/**
 * Creates and returns a MimeTypes instance from the specified document.
 * @throws MimeTypeException if the type configuration is invalid
 */
public static MimeTypes create(Document document) throws MimeTypeException {
    MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();

    //For some reason the MimeTypesReader is missing
    new MimeTypesReader(mimeTypes).read(document);
    mimeTypes.init();
    return mimeTypes;
}
```

Make sure that you have supplied the full library and also the latest for that matter - `tika-1.14`. You could get it from one of [these Apache mirrors](https://tika.apache.org/download.html).

The source is part of the `tika-core.jar`, so make sure you have that on too.